# cannot start hive, Could not parse [${clusterHostInfo/webhcat_server_host|append(core-site/hadoop.proxyuser.HTTP.hosts]

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn, hdp

ENV:

- ambari 2.7
- HDP 3.1.0
- enbaled kerberos
- useing openldap

---

The cluster use kerberos. I unloaded KNOX after upgrading from 2.6. This happens whenever I install hive/hbase. And [I can't properly install KNOX...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840743/install-knox-error-indexerror-list-index-out-of-range)

when i add hive service , the yarn resourcemanager error .

```java
2019-04-24 13:41:15,621 WARN  util.MachineList (MachineList.java:<init>(112)) - Invalid CIDR syntax : ${clusterHostInfo/webhcat_server_host|append(core-site/hadoop.proxyuser.HTTP.hosts
2019-04-24 13:41:15,622 WARN  ipc.Server (Server.java:logException(2724)) - IPC Server handler 0 on 8141, call Call#0 Retry#0 org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.api.ResourceManagerAdministrationProtocolPB.refreshSuperUserGroupsConfiguration from 192.168.10.2:35354
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse [${clusterHostInfo/webhcat_server_host|append(core-site/hadoop.proxyuser.HTTP.hosts]
        at org.apache.commons.net.util.SubnetUtils.calculate(SubnetUtils.java:275)
        at org.apache.commons.net.util.SubnetUtils.<init>(SubnetUtils.java:51)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.MachineList.<init>(MachineList.java:108)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.MachineList.<init>(MachineList.java:82)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.MachineList.<init>(MachineList.java:74)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.DefaultImpersonationProvider.init(DefaultImpersonationProvider.java:98)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.ProxyUsers.refreshSuperUserGroupsConfiguration(ProxyUsers.java:75)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.ProxyUsers.refreshSuperUserGroupsConfiguration(ProxyUsers.java:85)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.AdminService.refreshSuperUserGroupsConfiguration(AdminService.java:505)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.AdminService.refreshSuperUserGroupsConfiguration(AdminService.java:488)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.api.impl.pb.service.ResourceManagerAdministrationProtocolPBServiceImpl.refreshSuperUserGroupsConfiguration(ResourceManagerAdministrationProtocolPBServiceImpl.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.ResourceManagerAdministrationProtocol$ResourceManagerAdministrationProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(ResourceManagerAdministrationProtocol.java:275)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:524)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1025)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:876)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:822)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2682)
```

May I ask what caused it? Has Hcat been removed from [the HDP 3.x document](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.7.3.0/bk_ambari-upgrade-major/content/bhvr_changes_upgrade_hdp3_amb27.html)? Why would automatically configure `webhcat_server_host`?

Now this kind of problem appears, how should I solve?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you please check core-sire.xml , if any parameter hadoop.proxyuser.HTTP.hosts exists and what is value?

Comment: hi @Shubhangi ,this value is `<value>${clusterHostInfo/webhcat_server_host|append(core-site/hadoop.proxyuser.HTTP.hosts, \\,, true)}</value>` . when i reinstall hive, and restart yarn, it will down and also report the above error.

Comment: This is incorrect value. Due to this incorrect value you are hitting error reported in question. Value should be hostname or IP of machine where webhcat is installed.